# Will I keep the French nationality after divorce?

Tags: french-citizens, divorce

I was married with a French person for 7 years, and applied for French citizenship on the sixth year of our marriage - long after obtaining the legal right for application. However, we got divorced one month after I got the French citizenship.

According to the law, if you end your marriage within 12 months of acquiring citizenship, it is assumed that you presented your case for naturalization in a fraudulent manner. Does this apply to all cases, or each case shall be elaborated individually? Is there a way to keep my citizenship, since the marriage itself was not a fraud?

Comment: It applies to all cases and your situation does seem difficult, but it's not a *présomption irréfragable* so you might *in theory* be able to prove otherwise (i.e. that there was no fraud). What *présomption* means is that the state does not need to prove anything, the burden of proof is on you. Also, it seems that if the state does not bring a case against you within two years, then the *présomption* does not apply anymore. In any case, you should speak to a lawyer.

Comment: Incidentally, what matters is the *communauté de vie*, even postponing the divorce but living apart would not be good enough.

Comment: Do you have any other citizenship currently? International treaties forbid France to revoke citizenship from a person that has no other citizenship.

Comment: @relaxed that's an answer more than it is a comment

Answer (score -2):

I think it is 2 years, not one year, but from the date they accepted your file, not the date you were notified of approval.  And that is only if they are notified of the divorce and issue a new birth certificate to you within those 2 years--and then catch on about the dates, and then want to pursue you...I think, I am no expert.  Considering the age of this original post, wondering how this ended for you, charlotte?  I think posting current status, or ultimate resolution when there is one, would be helpful for others.

Comment: Sorry, but three times *I think* without further references does not make a good enough answer. This is more of a comment.

Comment: Downvoted for exactly the same reasons as posed by Jan Doggen, above.